# Можно ли создать объект внутри класса php?

Tags: php, ооп

Допустим, есть 3 класса:

```
class A {

}

class B {

}

class C {
  function A(){
     $a = new A();
     $b = new B();

  }
}
```

Можно ли в одном из классов в конструкторе или методе создать экземпляр другого класса?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно, а почему бы нет.

Comment: Тогда можно здесь же задам вопрос, скажем, есть массив данных. Выгодней и правильней передать его сразу объекту класса или по отдельности каждый элемент массива, например `foreach($arr as $val) { $obj = new Articles($val);}` Или `$obj = new Articles($arr);`

Comment: Лучше сразу весь массив передавать.

Comment: Дело в том, что в каждом элементе массива (многомерный) имеется значение type, проверка типа которой создает объект нужного класса: Articles, News, Comment. Я могу создать еще один класс, прокручивающий весь массив, и вызывая нужный экземпляр класса - но это не так, как вы мне советуйте, - весь массив. Какой выход?

Comment: @Vasile, опишите, что этот код вообще делает.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно можно

> Дело в том, что в каждом элементе массива (многомерный) имеется значение type, проверка типа которой создает объект нужного класса: Articles, News, Comment. Я могу создать еще один класс, прокручивающий весь массив, и вызывая нужный экземпляр класса - но это не так, как вы мне советуйте, - весь массив. Какой выход?

посмотрите паттерны 
[Фабрика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) 
[стратегия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))